# Loosing recycler view data on changing tabs

Tags: performance, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have made a app with 4 tabs (fragments). Tab 1 and Tab 4 have recycler view with image data coming through Picasso. Once the images load on lets say Tab1, its all good if I move to Tab 2 or Tab 3 and come back to Tab 1, the images and list remains populated. The problem comes when I go to Tab 4 which has another recycler view with images coming from Picasso. Same happens when I move out of Tab4. This makes it quite slow.
Why is the cache of recycler view images getting removed once i move to a Tab with different recycler view?

```
Watchfaces_model watchfacesModel=watchFacesList.get(i);

watchface_viewHolder.watchfaceText1.setText(watchfacesModel.getWatchFaceName1());


watchfaceRef= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("watchfaces/"+watchfacesModel.getImage1()+".png");

watchfaceRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        Picasso.get().load(uri)
                 .into(watchface_viewHolder.watchface1);
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle failed download
        // ...

        Toast.makeText(mctx, "Problem in loading Watchfaces", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your fragment's view is probably getting destroyed. I assume you're using `ViewPager`, so you can increase offscreen page limit to prevent that, or if you use same kind of adapter in each tab - use shared `RecycledViewPool` between all `RecyclerViews`.

Comment: Looks spot on, thanks.